# How can I convert this native SQL to HQL/JPQL or a Criteria Query using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
SELECT T1.ORGANIZATIONID, T1.CODE, T1.RFQCATEGORYID, T1.OWNERID,
T1.PARTCOUNT, T1.DESCRIPTION,T1.STATUSCODE, T1."COMMENT", T1.CREATEID,
T1.CREATEDATE, T1.UPDATEID, T1.UPDATEDATE, T2.CODE, T2.DESCRIPTION,
T3.ORGANIZATIONNAME, T3.ORGANIZATIONURL, T4.SALUTATION, T4.FIRSTNAME,
T4.LASTNAME, T4.EMAIL,T4.FINANCIAL_LIMIT, T5.ORGANIZATIONNAME
USR_ORGNAME,T5.ORGANIZATIONURL USR_ORGURL, T6.STARTDATE, T6.ENDDATE,
T6.OPENDATE, T6.RFQID, T6.PARTNUMBER,
T7.RFQTYPEID,T1.CURRENCYID,T1.MINQUOTECOUNT,T1.ISMATCHING,T1.ISMULTICURR,
T1.ESTIMATEDVALUE,T1.RAENABLED,T1.PAYMENTENABLED,T1.ISPRICEACPTINRA,
T8.DESCRIPTION AS RFQTYPEDESC , T1.FOREIGNCURRONLY , T1.DELEGATE ,
T1.LOCATIONID ,T6.INITIATERAID ,T10.AUTHENTICATIONCODE
,T6.DOCUMENTSALEENDDATE,T1.OWNER_DIGITAL_CERT_ID , T1.ANNUALVALUE ,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM EPS.ORGLOCATION WHERE LOCATION_ID =
T1.LOCATIONID AND ORGID = T1.ORGANIZATIONID ) >0 THEN  (SELECT
DESCRIPTION FROM EPS.ORGLOCATION WHERE LOCATION_ID = T1.LOCATIONID AND
ORGID = T1.ORGANIZATIONID) ELSE '' END AS LOCATIONDESC,
T1.MATIHINGVALUE,T1.SKIPQUOTE,T1.WCENABLED,T1.LOADTYPE,T6.DISALLOWBIDREV,T6.UPDATEDATE
AS RFQDATE_UPDATEDATE,T1.SIGNED,T1.ENCRYPTED,T1.OLDCODE
,T1.IMPACTBIDFLAG,T1.LOADING_EVALUATED,T1.ENCKEYENABLED,T1.VALUEFLAG,od.code
as designation, (SELECT MIN(UPDATEDATE) FROM EPS.HRFQ WHERE RFQID =
T1.RFQ_ID AND STATUSCODE= 'A' ) PUBLISH_DATE,LCNCMATCHING, T1.BOQ,
B.DESCRIPTION AS BOQDESC, T6.PHYSICALDOCSUBENDDATE, T1.AUCTIONSTYLE,
T1.AUCTIONTYPE, T1.AUCTIONSTATUS, T1.AUCTIONFILENAME,
T1.AUCTIONCOMMENT,T1.ITEMSUBMITBY, T1.AUCTIONWINNER  FROM EPS.RFQ T1
LEFT JOIN EPS.BOQ B ON T1.BOQ=B.BOQ_ID left outer join (select * from
EPS.RFQDATE where partnumber=?) T6 on t6.RFQID=t1.RFQ_ID left outer
join EPS.RFQRFQTYPE T7 on t7.RFQID=t1.RFQ_ID,EPS.RFQCAT T2,
EPS.ORGANIZATION T3,EPS."USER" T4 left outer join eps.orgdesignation
od on od.designation_id=t4.designationid, EPS.ORGANIZATION T5,
EPS.AUTHENTICATION T10, EPS.RFQTYPE T8 WHERE T1.RFQCATEGORYID =
T2.RFQCAT_ID AND T1.ORGANIZATIONID = T3.ORGANIZATION_ID AND T1.OWNERID
= T4.USER_ID AND T4.ORGANIZATIONID = T5.ORGANIZATION_ID AND T10.USERID = T4.USER_ID AND T4.ORGANIZATIONID = T10.ORGANIZATIONID AND T1.RFQ_ID = ?  AND T8.RFQTYPE_ID = T7.RFQTYPEID
```

I want to convert it into hibernate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here.

1. If you want to use your SQL as-is, you use `createNativeQuery` in order to supply a potentially database dependent SQL.  You can supply compliant SQL that will run across all of your potential database vendors to avoid any database dependence issues, but this is definitely an option, particularly when you need to make use of certain database features.
2. Use JPQL/HQL or Criteria API.  This is essentially an abstraction atop of SQL itself allowing you to write your query in a language or way that is agnostic to the database as Hibernate will translate it for you to your database platform's syntax where applicable.

Your native query is somewhat complex so my suggestion if you want to use option (2) would be to decompose it into simpler parts and build upon each step iteratively until you have what you need.

The first thing to note is your base query is against a table named `RFQ` by `ID`.  If you don't have an entity that represents your `RFQ` table, create one and expose the basic string and numeric attributes which you're trying to return from this base table.  Then in order to query against this you would write

```
List<Rfq> rfqs = session
  .createQuery( "SELECT r FROM Rfq r WHERE r.id = :id", Rfq.class )
  .setParameter( "id", rfqId )
  .getResultList();
```

From this point its a matter of building additional entities and relationships between your `RFQ` table and the joined tables, the attributes in each one, and then returning them as a part of the select clause as desired.